# JCL: How to read file name and find the specific string

Tags: sas, mainframe, jcl

I need to read the file name in JCL and find specific string in that. If string present then i need to set the flag variable.
Example:

```
000063 //SETVARS  SET RUNMODE=AY,                           
000064 //         MGRTMODE=M,                               
000065 //         PARMFILE=BASXXXX.T1.XXXX.JIRA.T011746
```

If "PARMFILE" contains "JIRA", then set JIRAFLAG = Y else JIRAFLAG = N. I need to pass the JIRAFLAG to another JCL/SAS job to process further.

Thanks!
Bharathi

---

SAS:

```
000083   /**/                                              
000084   %LET CHKFILE  = %SCAN(&SYSPARM,1,+);              
000085   %put &CHKFILE ;                                   
000086   %GLOBAL JIRAFLG ;                                 
000087   %MACRO CHK ;                                      
000088   %LET TSTVAL = %SCAN(&CHKFILE,4,.) ;               
000089   %PUT &TSTVAL;                                     
000090   %IF &TESTVAL EQ 'JIRA' %THEN %LET JIRAFLG = 'Y' ; 
000091   %ELSE %LET JIRAFLG = 'N' ;                        
000092   %PUT &JIRAFLG ;                                   
000093   %MEND CHK;                                        
000094   %CHK ;
```

Comment: You'll need REXX or something to parse the input file name

Comment: That is not how JCL works.  You could pass the filename to a Program (Cobol/Rexx etc) and it would issue a return code based on wether JIRA was present or not. You could then test Return code (COND or IF)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and what `scheduling` system do you have ???

Comment: Once you submit your JCL it cannot be changed. In fact, one it has been processed by the reader/interpreter it is 'discarded' and job execution processes the control blocks created by the reader/interpreter.

Comment: You can't pass back to JCL for a future step. However, one idea is to split the job into two steps, and have this SAS program dynamically build JCL that would be submitted, and specify the JIRAFLG as a symbolic parameter (either for a `PROC` or `SET` or both).

Comment: @Bharathiraja, The way you passed variable into sas is fine, all you need is a data _null_ step and use if find(&CHKFILE.,'JIRA')>1 then flag ='y';
or
Even better way is to use a inline sas from JCL, you can give the vaiable directly, you dont have to use SETVAR.

Answer (score 0):

JCL does not provide a scripting language per se although it is intuitive to think of it that way because of the JCL Symbols and conditionals.

I'm not a SAS buy but it seems like your SAS sample does the scanning.  I'd suggest that you have a STEP where you parse the `PARMFILE` statement and set a known return code of your choice.  For instance, choose a return code of 1.

Follow that with another step that when the return code is 1 executes the program you want to process when JIRA is in the `PARMFILE`.  Since you mentioned a seperate job you could submit another job through `INTRDR`.

There are ways to accomplish what you want you just need to be creative.  As I said, the conditionals and JCL Symbols lure many people into thinking scripting which is unfortunately not how it works.

Answer (score -1):

SRCHFOR 'YOURSTRING',W (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.f54u200/sfcmdfgrr.htm)

and then check here for conditional processing

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ieab600/iea3b6_Examples_of_IF_THEN_ELSE_ENDIF_statement_constructs.htm

Comment: Thank you all, I don't have feasibility to use the REXX here, so I was tried in INLINE SAS %LET TSTVAL = %SCAN(&CHKFILE,4,.) ; (Refer question section for full code), but from SAS am NOT able to pass the JIRA flag back to JCL.